# Example of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G$ is not cyclic but $G/H$ is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to give an example of a group $G$ and a proper normal subgroup $H$, where $G$ is not cyclic, but $G/H$ is.  I have messed with $D_3$ but do not see a subgroup that works.  Also, I have seen that $V_4$ is an example, but I have not seen this group yet.  Does anyone have a different example?

I have messed around with:

I have messed around with this a little bit, but to no luck. I have S3. I was messing with H={(1,2,3),(3,1,2),(2,3,1)}. I'm not sure if this works because I am not sure what G/H is. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should realise that the subgroup $H$ in Ian Coley's answer is the same as the subgroup you have given here. However, you are presenting the elements of $S_3$ in an odd way. It is best if you use "disjoint cycle notation", so what you write as $(1, 2, 3)$ is the empty cycle (so write as $Id$ or $1$ or $e$ or something), while $(3,1,2)$ would be written as $(1, 3, 2)$ (this says that $1\rightarrow 3$, $3\rightarrow 2$, $2\rightarrow 1$, by reading from right to left) while $(2, 3, 1)$ would be written as $(1, 2, 3)$.

Comment: (There is nothing wrong with using permutations on paper, but they come across badly here. Also, permutations are slower to compute with, and it is often harder to see what is going on. Disjoint cycles give you more visual information.)

Answer (score 3):

Just for giving another example, consider $S_n$  and $A_n$ for some proper positive integers $n$.

Comment: I have messed around with this a little bit, but to no luck. I have $S_3$.  I was messing with $H=\{(1,2,3),(3,1,2),(2,3,1)\}$.  I'm not sure if this works because I am not sure what $G/H$ is.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1234: your $H$ is really $\mathbb Z_3$ and it works good because the symmetric group $S_3$ is an extension of $H$ by $\mathbb Z_2$. This is what you are looking for. Also I suggest to have a look to Ian's point of views.

Answer (score 2):

Take an abelian group of order $4$ that's not cyclic (namely, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$), and a subgroup of order $2$. It must be normal, since the group is abelian.

(Really, though, this is just the Klein $4$-group that you've mentioned).

---

As a completely different example, choose any non-cyclic group with a subgroup of index $2$, or alternatively, any time when $2 |H| = |G|$. Then $H$ is necessarily normal in $G$, and the quotient $G/H$ is cyclic of order $2$. Symmetric and alternating groups furnish such examples.

Comment: Any abelian group of order $6$ is cyclic.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Wow, I'm clearly not thinking today.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the nontrivial semidirect product of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$, where $p<q$ and $p\equiv 1\mod q$. This group has a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup, say $Q\triangleleft G$, and since $|G/Q|=p$, it must be $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, which is cyclic.

In fact, $D_3\cong S_3$ satisfies these conditions. The subgroup $\{e,r,r^2\}$ (where $r$ is the rotation element) is normal in $D_3$, and its quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.